# Resources.NotFoundException only on some devices

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm fetching a color like this and it is returning 0 for a few devices that I'm seeing on crash reports. They are all in `res/values/colors.xml`. Ex.     `<color name="firstcolor">#A8A77A</color>`. The `colorString` is dynamic.

```
int primaryColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context,
            context.getResources().getIdentifier(colorString.toLowerCase(),
                    context.getString(R.string.color), context.getPackageName()));
```

I've tested on these devices and it works:
LG G5 (7.0)
- Nokia N1 (5.1.1)
- Motorola G (5.1)
- Samsung Core Prime (4.4.4)

The crash reports are from these:
Samsung Ace 4 (4.4.2)
- Sony Xperia M5 E5603 (6.0) - NG Envy (4.4.2)

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1133)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:815)
   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:434)
```

Any way to find out why it doesn't work for some of these devices?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was `toLowerCase()`. A capital `I` was being transformed to a `ı` instead of `i` for some Locales, which resulted in not being able to find the resource by identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the project and see

Also Just use

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.firstcolor)
```

Comment: No, I need to get them dynamically with the id. There are numerous colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, you should defType as **color** in getIdentifier.

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(colorString.toLowerCase(), "color", context.getPackageName());

int primaryColor = ContextCompat.getColor(resourceId);
```

Comment: My `R.string.color` is "color". So this is the same as yours.